# Uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{\sin nx}{n^ {\ln n} } $, $ x\in \Bbb{R}$,

Tags: real-analysis

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{\sin nx}{n^ {\ln n} } $, $ x\in \Bbb{R}$, converges

A) only for $x=0$

B) uniform only for $x\in [-\pi, \pi] $

C) uniform for {$x \in \Bbb{R} $- {$n\pi:n\in\Bbb{Z}$}}

D) uniform for all $x \in \Bbb{R} $
$\implies$ let $u_n(x) =\sin nx$ . and $v_n(x) = \frac{1}{{n}^{\ln n}} $ then $s_n(x) =\sin x +\sin 2x +... + \sin nx$ = $\frac{{\sin \frac{nx} {2}} \sin \frac{(n+1)x}{2}}{\sin \frac{x} {2}}$
Hence $|s_n(x)|=|{\frac{1}{\sin \frac{x} {2}} |} $. Now if $x=0$ then $|s_n(x)|$ will be unbounded. Hence option A, B, D are false. If we consider C then $|s_n(x) |$ will be bounded there and$v_n(x)$ is a monotone decreasing sequence. So by Dirichlet test U.C.follows.
I request experts to check the above and help me refine my arguments if I am on the right track. Also any independent new ideas are cordially welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: once $n>e^2$, the $n$th summand is bounded in absolute value by $1/n^2$ uniformly in $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the Weierstrass M-test to prove the result. For $n\geq 3$ we have that $1 < \ln(3)\leq \ln(n)$ and so $\frac{1}{n^{\ln(n)}} \leq \frac{1}{n^{\ln(3)}}$. Then by $p-$test the series $\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{\ln(3)}}$ converges. Since $|\sin(n x)|\leq 1$. Then
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\Big|\frac{(-1)^n\sin(nx)}{n^{\ln(n)}}\Big|\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{\ln(n)}}\leq 1 + \frac{1}{2^{\ln(2)}}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{\ln(3)}} < \infty$$
Thus we have uniform convergence for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.